# Preciso clicar na DIV<Configuração Planificação> mas não consigo. Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Podem me ajudar? Não faço ideia de como clicar no botão **Configuração Planificação**

Tentei clicar usando o código abaixo:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='TBB_tbm2']/div[2]")).click();
```

Mas ele não me deixa interagir dessa forma diretamente, sei que tenho que usar o Iaction do Selenium, usando `.MoveToElement()` primeiro, mas ainda não funcionou com o `Xpath`. qual é a alternativa?

Código da Página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<link id=favicon rel='SHORTCUT ICON' href='r/std/static/favicon7.ico'>
<link rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' href='r/std/static/favicon7.png'/>
<link rel='apple-touch-startup-image' href='r/std/static/splash.png' />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='default'><script>document.windowid='1901';document.code='=gTGBoEBCprStkUF';window.timeShift=new Date().getTime()-1653676049658;window.sessionStart=1653658446591;</script><script src='utils.js?id=MTY1MzY0ODQ5OTQwNA' language='JavaScript'></script><script>registerView('GCWM_6290d34c');</script><script src='communication.js?id=MTY1MzY0ODQ5OTQwNA' language='JavaScript'></script><script src='ui.js?id=MTY1MzY0ODQ5OTQwNA' language='JavaScript'></script><script src='validation.js?id=MTY1MzY0ODQ5OTQwNA' language='JavaScript'></script><script src='utils_wfm.js?id=MTY1MzY0ODQ5OTQwNA' language='JavaScript'></script><link id='gcbss' rel='STYLESHEET' href='Newhall.css?id=MTY1MzY0ODUwNjcwOQ' type='text/css'></head><body onUnload='onunload()' onLoad='onload();' class='desktop'><script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
document.title='Geocall: ';
// -->
</script><style id='barstyle' media='(device-width:0)'>#barcont {transform:translateX(-100%); -ms-transform:translate(-100%); -webkit-transform:translate(-100%);}  #area {margin-left:0px;transition-delay:0ms;} </style><script language='JavaScript'>
<!--
barSetup();
// -->
</script><div id='barcont' onmouseenter="window.tbwheel=0;if (event.clientY>20) barSet('on');" onmouseleave="if (!window.eventing) barSet('off');"><img onClick='barSwitch();' id='baricon' onmouseleave="afterTransition(this,'bariconLeave', function(){event.stopPropagation();})" onload='activateSvg(this);' src='r/std/wm/menu.svg'><div id='clientbar'><table id='theBar' cellspacing='0' style='table-layout:fixed;height:100%;' border='0' cellpadding='0' onmousemove='swipeMenuMouseMove(event);'><tr id='tbLogo'><td style='height:1px'><div class='logo'><img id='mainLogo' width='100%' border='0' src='r/eorder/static/logo_eorder.png'></div></td></tr><tr id='tbIdentity'><td style='height:1px'><div id='identity' class='identity'><div onClick='if(notSelecting()) toggleIdentityBox();' onmousedown='event.preventClosingMenu=true;' class='user' ontouchstart='event.preventClosingMenu=true;'><div id='userImage' class='iconIdentity'><img align='absbottom' class='icon' alt='User' src='r/std/icons/usermale64.png' tooltip=''></div><div id='userData' class='data'>RODRIGUES DOS SANTOS<br> GABRIEL</div></div><div id='userActions' class='actions box'><div><div class='description'><div>RODRIGUES DOS SANTOS GABRIEL</div><div class='factory'>EnelSaoPaulo</div></div><div ontouchstart='event.preventClosingMenu=true;' class='actionIdentity' onmousedown='event.preventClosingMenu=true;'><img src='r/std/static/pixel.gif' class='icon Enabled icon_logout' draggable=false onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'','1901','Logout','','','','Desconectar do Sistema?');" ></div><div ontouchstart='event.preventClosingMenu=true;' onmousedown='event.preventClosingMenu=true;' class='actionIdentity'><img src='r/std/static/pixel.gif' class='icon Enabled icon_info' draggable=false onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'','1901','Info#','','','','');" ></div></div></div><div id='tbTime' class='time box'><div class='iconIdentity'><img src='r/std/static/pixel.gif' class='icon icon_time' draggable=false></div><input date-format='dd/MM/yyyy' id='clock' class='data' readonly></div></div></td></tr><tr><td style='height:100%;'><div style='height:100%; position:relative;'><div id='barScroller' onmousedown='this.automatic=false;' onscroll='if (!this.automatic) window.tbwheel=1; closeIdentityBox();' layout='FIXED_IDENTITY' onwheel='window.tbwheel=1;' class='scroller'><table cellspacing='0' style='table-layout:fixed;width:100%; height:100%;' border='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='height:1px;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:20px;'><div id='tbm2' class='tb'><div id='TBH_tbm2' onClick="javascript:showMenu('tbm2','tbm2', true, true)" class='tbh'>Menu Principal</div><div id='TBB_tbm2' class='tbb'><div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.0','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/anagraficamagazzino64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Módulo Básico</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.1','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/calendario64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Agenda</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.2','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/articoli64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Gestão Materiais</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.3','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/faq64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Pré-Operacional</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.4','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/consultazindicatori64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Fiscalização</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.5','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/allega64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Gestão Avisos</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.8','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/conf64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Configuração Planificação</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.9','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/ordine64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Lista TdC</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.11','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/pianificazioneConsegne64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Planejamento</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.12','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/calcoloindicatori64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Monitoramento</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.13','',''); " class='tbi tbiSel' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/usertelefono64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Help Desk</div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.14','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/email64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Mail </div></div>
<div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1902','Menu','','','.15','',''); " class='tbi' ><div ><div  class='tbiIcon'><img src='r/std/icons/Attrezzi64.png' class="icon" draggable=false></div></div><div >Ferramentas</div></div>
</div></div></td></tr><tr><td style='vertical-align:middle;'></td></tr><tr><td style='height:1px;vertical-align:bottom;'></td></tr></table></div></div></td></tr></table></div></div><div id='area'><div style='display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; -ms-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column;'><div class='Stack'>&nbsp;</div><div id='workArea' style='-ms-flex: 1; flex: 1;'>&nbsp;</div></div></div><img id='workIcon' class='workIcon' style='position:fixed;top:2px;left:3px;z-index:200;display:none;' src='r/std/static/favicon7.png'><script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
function setupStateParam() {
    document.telephoneBar=0;
    if (window.top.frames.state!=null) {
        window.top.frames.state.document.login='null';
        window.top.frames.state.document.pwd='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.extension='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.extensionChat='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.agentId='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.queue='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.ipCallCenter='';
        window.top.frames.state.document.portCallCenter=null;
        window.top.frames.state.document.outboundpreview=0;
        window.top.frames.state.document.EnableChat=false;
    }
}
setupStateParam();
function loadState() {
    if (window.top.frames.state != null && typeof window.top.frames.state.setupFrame == 'function')
        window.top.frames.state.setupFrame();
}
function callEvent(event,params) {
    var newLocation = location.protocol + '//'+location.host+location.pathname;
    newLocation += '?__wm=GCWM_6290d34c&_an1901=OcxEvent&_snevent=' + event + '&_snparams=' + params +'&code==gTGBoEBCprStkUF';
    location.replace(newLocation);
}
if(window.top.frames.state!=null) window.top.frames.state.document.canCallClose=0;
showMenu('tbm1','tbm1',true,false);showMenu('tbm2','tbm2',true,false);try {
SizeListener.attachOnViewport(); SizeListener.attachOnWorkarea();
} catch (e) {/*the responsive grid will be rendered correctly once the page has been loaded*/}
// -->
</script><img class='wmhandler' onload='activateSvg(this)' src='r/std/wm/eye.svg' style='fill:red' onclick='viewManager();'></body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

tive minha situação resolvida com a função abaixo. public void

```
ClicarMenu(By bynome)
        {

            IWebElement SplitCaseYes = driver.FindElement(bynome);
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", SplitCaseYes);

            //IAction acaoClicar = new Actions(driver)
            //.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(bynome))
            //.Click(driver.FindElement(bynome))
            //.Build();
            //acaoClicar.Perform();
        }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).